# how to return run default content for intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I used one of the best shortcuts for Intellij:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>

And it runs default content, which will be open.

I don't know how, but now it really do nothing.

All other short cuts are ok. And this one is dead (doesn't work anymore).

***How to return to this useful short cut (or general set to Intellij default)?***

Comment: Does the class you are focused on have a `public static void main` method?

Comment: @vikingsteve yes, exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since you have a `psvm` method, and your focus is in the code for that class when you press the shortcut, and given your caps key isn't on, then you should see IntelliJ try to *make* before running your code.

Do you see it *Making* ?

If not, it's likely another plugin or action has stolen the key shortcut.

Go to *Settings* -> Ide Settings / Keymap, and type `RunClass` in the search box.

You should see this: *Run context configuration* -> `Ctrl + Shift + F10`

If the key shortcut is missing, assign it.

Hope this helps.

P.S. I was recently using the Haskell IntelliJ plugin which conflicted with this shortcut. Disabling it did the trick to restore it.